# recursive call for SPListItem Update method when called from a call receiver of this item with UppdatedItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint

hi i have fallen in a serious problem about the SPListItem Update method. when i make a event receiver to intercept SPlistitem change or update with SPItemEventReceiver UpdatedItem method, i bogged down in big problem, who i could escape from:

sc:

```
   public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);

        SPList list = properties.List;

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;

        if ("Oui" == properties.ListItem["Envoyé vers le Directeur"].ToString())
        {
            SPListItem copyItem = item;

            MoveItemsToFolder(properties, list, "Dossiers envoyés Rédaction", copyItem);

            item["Service"] = "direction";
            item.Update();

            string[] cols = { "Envoyé vers le Directeur", "Archivé" };
            HideColumns(list, cols);

        }
        else if ("Oui" == properties.ListItem["Validé par le Directeur"].ToString())
        {

            SPListItem copyItem = item;

            MoveItemsToFolder(properties, list, "Direction", copyItem);

            item["Service"] = "bureauOrdre";
            item.Update();

            string[] cols = { "Validé par le Directeur", "Envoyé vers le Directeur" };
            HideColumns(list, cols);
        }
        else if ("Oui" == properties.ListItem["Archivé"].ToString())
        {

            SPListItem copyItem = item;

            MoveItemsToFolder(properties, list, "Archives", copyItem);

            item["Service"] = "Archive";
            item.Update();

            string[] cols = { "Validé par le Directeur", "Envoyé vers le Directeur" };
            HideColumns(list, cols);
        }
        else
        {

            item["Service"] = "redaction";
            item.Update();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You do not want it to call your event receiver again when you call update in your event receiver (stop recursive calls of event receiver)?

Comment: Sorry, what? Do not fully understand you...

Comment: who i could stop event receiver

Comment: try to set EventFiringEnabled property to false at the beginning of the method and back to true at the end. this.EventFiringEnabled = false.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling any `Update()` methods in you event receiver set `EventFiringEnabled` property to false. This will disable any event receivers from firing. At the end of your method enable them again by settings this property to true.